# web programming_javascript: Error with Grade result in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have create a student information javascript.Everything is ok but i have a problem in the result of student's grade.It's alway show grade F every score.Ex.when total score is 100 it's show F but when total score is 500 it still show F.
Here is my code of java and html

```
'
var Column= ["ID", "Name","Gender","Javascript","Data structure","Network","VB.net","Corel Draw","Total", "Average","Grade"];
var arr = ["","","","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",""];
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var x;
var grade;
    if(arr[8]>=450 && arr[8]<500)
      grade= "A";
   else if(arr[8]>=400 && arr[8]<450)
      grade= "B";
   else if(arr[8]>=350 && arr[8]<400)
      grade= "C";
    else if(arr[8]>=300 && arr[8]<350)
      grade= "D";
   else if(arr[8]>=250 && arr[8]<300)
      grade= "E";
    else (arr[8]<250)
      grade= "F";
x = parseInt(window.prompt("Number of Student"));

for (j = 0 ; j <= x-1 ; j++) { 
//
for (i = 0 ; i <= 7; i++) { 
arr[i] = window.prompt("Please Input " + Column[i] );
}
arr[8]= parseInt(arr[3]) + parseInt(arr[4]) + parseInt(arr[5]) + parseInt(arr[6]) +     parseInt(arr[7]);
arr[9]= parseInt(arr[8])/5;
arr[10]=grade;

document.write("<tr>");

for (i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++) { 
//
document.write("<td>"+ arr[i] + "</td> ");


}
document.write("</tr>");
//

}
document.write("</table>");
```

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Korm-Chantola</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style for table.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="watermark">KORM-CHANTOLA<br>ID-B121561<br>ROOM-A201</div>
<center>

<h1>STUDENT SCORE INFORMATION</h1>

<table  class="table1" 
        border="5" padding="2px" 
        width="700px">
    <tr >
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>JavaScript</th>
        <th>Data Structure</th>
        <th>Network</th>
        <th>VB.net</th>
        <th>Corel Draw</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Average</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
    </tr>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript.js"></script>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

```
table.table1,td,th{
border: 1px solid black;
} 
table.table1 td {
text-align: center;
height: 50px;
vertical-align: bottom;
padding: 15px;
background-color:#CCCCCC;
color:#0D3821;

}

table.table1 th{
    color:white;
    background-color:#3B3B99;
    padding: 10px;
 }
h1 {
text-shadow: 15px 10px 8px black;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
color:#1C127D;
}  

body {
background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
.watermark {
position: left;
opacity: 0.25;
font-size: 2em;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

![This is Screenshot of problem][10]

Comment: `else (arr[8]<250) grade= "F";` is invalid and should either be changed to `else if (arr...) grade ...;` or `else grade ...;`.

Comment: And get rid of the `<center>` tag while you're at it.

Comment: it still not work.You can test it yourself.look at my if conditional Ex.if(arr[8]>=450 && arr[8]<500) grade= "A"; when i test in browser arr[8](total score) are 470.so it should be show Grade A but it not it show Grade F.every score are grade F.i hope everybody can help me plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will do because for grade A you are testing if it is less than 500. It's not so it will fall through to the else condition. Change to <=500 and it should work for grade A.

Second problem is the (arr[8]<250). The else condition is executing this as the result of the if block. The following line of code is grade="F" for it will always be set to F no matter what happened in the if block. Lose the (arr[8]<250).

With these two changes it should work as required.

**Hint:** Even for one line blocks within an if statement I prefer to wrap the block in {}. This way it is a lot easier to see what is going on (in the above case it would throw up a syntax error).